# How to reverse certain tuple (user input by index of the list) in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have tuples in a list:

```
  a=[(1.51, 0.0), (0.93, 0.0), (0.57, 0.0), (0.35, 0.0), (166.0, 0.0), (5.92, 0.0), (15.36, 0.0), (9.89, 0.0), (30.2, 0.0), (5.2, 0.0), (13.31, 0.82)]
```

Now the user will give indexes of the list as a list as the input and I want to reverse the tuple at that indexes only.

```
#b=Input the index positions as list
b=[7,10] # positions at which to reverse the tuple
```

So for this exmaple, I want to reverse the tuple at index 7 and 10 only.
What's the most efficient way to do this? All I can think is with 2 nested for loops and that's very inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the builtin `reversed`:

```
a = [(1.51, 0.0), (0.93, 0.0), (0.57, 0.0), (0.35, 0.0), (166.0, 0.0), (5.92, 0.0), (15.36, 0.0), (9.89, 0.0), (30.2, 0.0), (5.2, 0.0), (13.31, 0.82)]
b = [7,10]
for index in b:
    a[index] = tuple(reversed(a[index]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
 a = [j[::-1] if i in b else j for i,j in enumerate(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing.

> a=[(1.51, 0.0), (0.93, 0.0), (0.57, 0.0), (0.35, 0.0), (166.0, 0.0), (5.92, 0.0), (15.36, 0.0), (9.89, 0.0), (30.2, 0.0), (5.2, 0.0), (13.31, 0.82)]

> output = a[:b[0]] + a[b[1]:b[0]:-1] + a[b[1]+1:]

> print(output)

> [(1.51, 0.0), (0.93, 0.0), (0.57, 0.0), (0.35, 0.0), (166.0, 0.0), (5.92, 0.0), (15.36, 0.0), (13.31, 0.82), (5.2, 0.0),
> (30.2, 0.0)]